# OpenCV no CodBloks c++

Tags: c++

Alguém pode me ajudar, instalei a biblioteca opencv, e configurei ela no codeblocks, mas mesmo assim quando vou compilar o projeto, dis[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você não disse como configurou a biblioteca no Code::Blocks. Mas se você usou o "Project Build Options" então precisa fazer para a configuração Release e para a configuração Debug.
Se fez só para uma configuração não vai funcionar na outra.

Você também está usando uma versão muito antiga do Code::Blocks. A versão mais recente é a 17.12

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu sei bibliotecas desse tipo, precisam antes de ser inseridas no código, serem instaladas direto na máquina, quando trabalhei com openCV primeiro tive de instalar no core da máquina e depois fiz a instancia da biblioteca, talvez esteja faltando algum arquivo pra você.